Alternate derivation of an expectation for a Brownian martingale
I'm self studying Arguin's A First Course in Stochastic Calculus, and I'm struggling with the following exercise (Exercise 4.12):

Let $(B_{t}, t \geq 0)$ be a standard Brownian motion.  Consider for
$a, b > 0$ the stopping time $$\tau = \min_{t \geq 0} \{ t : B_{t} \geq a \text{ or } B_{t} \leq -b \}. $$

Show that $M_{t} = tB_{t} - \frac{1}{3}B_{t}^{3}$ is a martingale for the Brownian filtration.
Use 1. above to show that $\mathbb{E}[\tau B_{\tau}] = \frac{ab}{3} (a - b)$.
Argue that for any $\lambda > 0$ we have $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(\lambda B_{\tau} - \frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}\tau \right)\right] = 1$.
Find another proof of 2. using 3. above. (Hint: Taylor series)


I've answered the first three questions, but the fourth has left me stumped.
How do I answer it?

You could use $\exp(u) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n/n!$ to express the left side as a power series in $\lambda$. Because the right side is constant, the coefficients of $\lambda^k$ for $k\ge 1$ must all vanish. Focus on the coefficient of $\lambda^3$. (You'll need to compute $\Bbb E[B^3_\tau]$; bear in mind that $B_\tau$ has just two values, $a^3$ and $-b^3$.)
(N.B. Because the random variable $B_\tau$ is bounded, the formula in 3. holds for all real $\lambda$.)
